# Taking into account Camera Direction in 3d models using Trig

Tags: trigonometry, 3d

I have been working on a 3d rendering project as code. I am a bit stumped on the math though.
I know how to render points using arctangent on an HTML canvas using JavaScript, like this:

```
     function Gen(x,y,z){
     xs = Math.sin(Math.atan(z/x)) * pix_rate; /*x, y and z are inputs; 
       xs and ys are screen coords; 
       pix_rate: coefficient to scale up xs or ys 
       to fit on screen from screen.width/Math.sin(fov)*/
     ys = Math.sin(Math.atan(y/x)) * pix_rate;
     return {"x":xs, "y":ys}; //What is given back to the function call
     }
```

I also have figured out how to account for the eye position, which I just subtract from each coordinate before I do those calculations.

What I cannot figure out is how to factor in the two different planes of directions the eye can be facing (azimuth and elevation). I have used a number of different methods that all have the same result. Also, is my math redundant? Thanks. This is not homework by the way, and I am in 8th grade, so apologies if I got something wrong.